# How to import multiple files with same name in python

Tags: python

I have following structure for a python project that generate source files:

```
/project_name/src/module_name0/scripts/generate.py
/project_name/src/module_name1/scripts/generate.py
...
/project_name/src/module_nameN/scripts/generate.py
```

I want use `generate` scripts from script located in:

```
/project_name/prj/generate_all.py
```

How may I import `generate` scripts from `generate_all`? I tried to add `/project_name/src/module_nameK` to `sys.path`, but because the files have same name one of them hides the others. I don't want to add `__init__.py` file in `module_nameK` folders as I have only other source files there.

Comment: you can always try "import xxx as yyy"

Comment: @Puciek This works, thanks! Unfortunately I can't accept a comment as answer

Comment: Now you can do that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always try:

```
import xxx as yyy
```

So for example if you want to rename MySQLdb to something easier to type, you could write

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [imp](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module.

### EDIT

I think you need `imp.load_source("somemodule.name", "full/path/to/your/module")`

---

Your can use `imp.load_module(name, ...)`

An example taken from python docs:

```
import imp
import sys

def __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None):
    # Fast path: see if the module has already been imported.
    try:
        return sys.modules[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # If any of the following calls raises an exception,
    # there's a problem we can't handle -- let the caller handle it.

    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)

    try:
        return imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        # Since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly.
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```